# how to display HTML menu based on Spring user authorities

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-security, authorization

we are implementing our project using java spring-security; I created user, role and privilege tables so that every user has one or more roles and every role has one or more privileges. Then I annotated rest APIs using `@PreAuthorize ("hasAuthority('privilege-name')")`. With these in mind, I have a question: how can we create HTML menu base on user permissions (privileges)? e.g. according to user roles, some menu items should not be displayed

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('privilege-name')">
  ... html ...
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: a little explanation about the solution can be helpful. You can quote the relevant information from the link shared to help OP understand your solution better.